# Navigate within opened page in webView using other view in Xamrain.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

Ok, I have a relatively simple question.

I have webView that is loaded by a customized HTML code created by my application. In that HTML, I set up points (using  tags) where I want the webView to jump to when the user clicks (selects) the point from a listView that has those points listed.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think you would need to [invoke some javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#invoking-javascript) on the `WebView` to cause it to navigate to an anchor on the page

Comment: I thought about that but How should I call the JavaScript code from out side the WebView?

Comment: Read the link I provided

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thnx ^^